# Reload a module while preserving it's variables

Tags: python

Suppose I have two modules, x and y.

x:

```
import random
a = []
a.append(random.randint(1,100)
```

y:

```
from importlib import reload
import x
reload(x)
```

Now what happens is, module x gets reloaded and because of line #2 in x, the list gets reset to an empty list. How can I prevent this without using another module z just to define the empty list?

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Reloading is fragile and wonky already without trying to customize it like that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree.. avoid reload at all costs.. too bad only certain IDE's detect/reload changes in code while you work..